# c# linq order of columns in generated sql

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6

I have three tables A, B e C and I'm using linq to get data from database. The problem is the column order in the generated sql.

As I learned, the first column should be `1 AS [C1]`. And indeed, if I join table B and table C, this is the first column. But if I join all tables (or just table A and B), the first column is a "random" column (doesn't matter the column order mapped in FluentAPI neither the column order in sql server, but I just can't believe that is just a random choice, because is always the same column). And all I think is "WHY?".

And maybe this could happened a lot of times before and I didn't noticed, but this time the "random" column is a nullable one. And when the EF gets null in the first column of a returned row, it sets null for entire row. A entire row that isn't null is set as null because of its first column and this is driven me crazy.

I did a lot of research of how the EF works, but I can't understand why this happen and how to avoid it. Any help or guidance will be appreciated.

```
Version of Entity: 6.1.3

Table A - DetalheArrecadacao
IDDetalheArrecadacao | bigint (PK)
IDArrecadacao        | bigint (FK)
Quantidade           | int  ---- column picked as first
Valor                | numeric
Ativo                | bit

Table B - DetalheArrecadacaoDinheiro
IDDetalheArrecadacaoDinheiro | bigint (PK)
IDDetalheArrecadacao         | bigint (FK)
Agencia                      | varchar
ContaCorrente                | varchar
Data                         | datetime
NumeroDocumento              | varchar
IDTipoBanco                  | tinyint (FK)
ChavePSN                     | varchar
IDUsuario                    | int (FK)

Table C - TipoBanco
IDTipoBanco | tinyint (PK)
Codigo      | varchar
Descricao   | varchar
Ativo       | bit

Linq
var result = (from dad in detalhesDinheiro 
              from b in bancos
              from da in detalhes
              where dad.IdTipoBanco == b.Id && dad.IdDetalheArrecadacao == da.Id && da.Ativo && da.IdArrecadacao == idArrecadacao
              select new
              {
                  Id = dad.Id,
                  IdDetalheArrecadacao = dad.IdDetalheArrecadacao,
                  DetalheArrecadacao = da,
                  IdTipoBanco = dad.IdTipoBanco,
                  Banco = b,
                  Agencia = dad.Agencia,
                  ContaCorrente = dad.ContaCorrente,
                  Data = dad.Data,
                  NumeroDocumento = dad.NumeroDocumento,
                  ChavePSN = dad.ChavePSN,
                  IDUsuario = dad.IDUsuario
              });

Generated SQL
    SELECT 
    [Extent3].[Quantidade] AS [Quantidade], 
    [Extent1].[IDDetalheArrecadacaoDinheiro] AS [IDDetalheArrecadacaoDinheiro], 
    [Extent1].[IDDetalheArrecadacao] AS [IDDetalheArrecadacao], 
    [Extent3].[IDDetalheArrecadacao] AS [IDDetalheArrecadacao1], 
    [Extent3].[IDArrecadacao] AS [IDArrecadacao], 
    [Extent3].[Valor] AS [Valor], 
    [Extent3].[Ativo] AS [Ativo], 
    [Extent1].[IDTipoBanco] AS [IDTipoBanco], 
    [Extent2].[IDTipoBanco] AS [IDTipoBanco1], 
    [Extent2].[Codigo] AS [Codigo], 
    [Extent2].[Descricao] AS [Descricao], 
    [Extent2].[Ativo] AS [Ativo1], 
    [Extent1].[Agencia] AS [Agencia], 
    [Extent1].[ContaCorrente] AS [ContaCorrente], 
    [Extent1].[Data] AS [Data], 
    [Extent1].[NumeroDocumento] AS [NumeroDocumento], 
    [Extent1].[ChavePSN] AS [ChavePSN], 
    [Extent1].[IDUsuario] AS [IDUsuario]
    FROM   [dbo].[DetalheArrecadacaoDinheiro] AS [Extent1]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[TipoBanco] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[IDTipoBanco] = 
    [Extent2].[IDTipoBanco]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[DetalheArrecadacao] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent1].
    [IDDetalheArrecadacao] = [Extent3].[IDDetalheArrecadacao]
    WHERE ([Extent3].[Ativo] = 1) AND ([Extent3].[IDArrecadacao] = @p__linq__0)
```

PS: Sorry, my tables are in portuguese.
PS2: If I miss something, tell me.
PS3: If you see an english mistake, I'm sorry, but it isn't my first language.

Comment: If you are a native Portuguese speaker, why not post the question on the Portugues Stack Overflow?

Comment: Also, why do you care about the generated SQL here? Does EF give you the correct data?

Comment: 1) I can reach more people in english, sad but true. 2) No, as the first column is nullable, when the value is null, the entire row becomes null.

Comment: "when the value is null, the entire row becomes null" Can you provide a simple repro of this?

Comment: why not update the Sql Query and Order By the specific columns you need ?